# Remove the top padding in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` with a background showing for the selected item

Here's the bottom navigation XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottombar_item_bg"/>
```

I want the items to match the bar height's and remove the top padding showing.

[image]

Comment: You can try setting `android:paddingTop="0dp"` under `BottomNavigationView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you true `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` here you put height as 50dp so try change height to `android:layout_height="35dp" or android:layout_height="40dp"`

Comment: No, actionBarSize is 48dp.